# Binding different Grizzly HttpHandlers to different NetworkListeners

Tags: java, grizzly

The [Grizzly documentation](http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/docbkx2.2/html/hsf-building-simple.html) states that

> all HttpHandlers added to the ServerConfiguration will be shared
>   across all listeners

Is there another way of binding different handlers to different ports?  Or will I have to multiply instantiate `HttpServer`?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind it to a `PortRange` i.e multiple ports

`NetworkListener(String name, String host, PortRange portRange)` [documented](http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/NetworkListener.html)

or

```
HttpServer httpServer = new HttpServer();

NetworkListener networkListener1 = new NetworkListener("sample-listener1", "localhost", 8888);
NetworkListener networkListener2 = new NetworkListener("sample-listener2", "localhost", 8889);
httpServer.addListener(networkListener1);
httpServer.addListener(networkListener2);
```

This way you can add multiple handlers for different ports

or (haven't tried but most probably work)

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer();
 server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(handler1);
 server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(handler2);
server.start()
```

Comment: But I want _different_ handlers bound to different ports.  Using a PortRange would just bind the same handler(s) to all the ports, no?

Comment: Could you include the HttpHandlers in your example?  I want `GET http://localhost:1234/` to call one handler, `GET http://localhost:5678/` to call another.

Comment: It's about serving different content using different handlers for different ports.

Comment: per httpserver instance only one HttpHandler will be present, in that case you need multiple instances of `HTTPServer` instances

Comment: Ok, that's as I suspected.  If you would like to edit your answer I'll accept :-)

Comment: sorry for earlier comment, it seems it might work see the edit.

Comment: Actually PortRange documentation is a bit misleading. It doesn't bind to all the ports within the range but to a random free one (doing multiple binding attempts to find a free port if necessary).