# Can Grizzly HttpServer serve dual NetworkListeners, one with client auth and one without?

Tags: authentication, grizzly

I want my HttpServer to provide a restricted set of services to authenticated clients and to provide 'public' services to any client.

Both services are encrypted using TLS - only the first requires client authentication.  I see how to create and configure two NetworkListeners - each on their own port and with appropriate SSLContext and Engine configurators - and how to add them to the HttpServer.

How can I associate different HttpHandlers to the different listeners?  Alternatively, how can I tell in a handler whether the client is authenticated?

[Binding different Grizzly HttpHandlers to different NetworkListeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770674/binding-different-grizzly-httphandlers-to-different-networklisteners) suggests I may need parallel HttpServers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are right there is no way to deploy HttpHandler to a specific NetworkListener, only to HttpServer. You can file an issue at [1], we'll address it once we have time. Contributions are also welcome ;)
2. In order to determine if the client is authenticated - you can try to get its certificate using Request attribute, like:

```java
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

if the attribute is not null - the client is authenticated.

[1] https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY/